# Can I make Windows Key + Tab behave like a normal Alt + Tab?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm using this apple keyboard on my PC at the moment (don't ask). The only major difference to me is that the `Command` key (acts like the `Windows` key) and the `Alt` key changed places. Therefor I keep hitting `Command` + `Tab` (so basically `Windows` key + `Tab`) when trying to switch between windows. So what I get instead of the fast `Alt` + `Tab` window is the annoying Windows Flip3D.

So my question is: can I make the `Windows` + `Tab` behave like a normal `Alt` + `Tab`?

Comment: I can't believe that's the only keyboard shortcut that messes you up on a regular basis. This happens to me all the time when using my MacBook Pro in Windows with an external keyboard. As jjlin suggests, SharpKeys is a brilliant solution; only caveat is it requires a restart. But it's definitely a "set it once and forget it" kind of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) might be able to remap the two keys.